# moment.js deprecation warning on ISO string?

Tags: momentjs

I've got the following javascript code utilizing the moment.js library. We've been having issues with conversions to/from utc.
The code below returns this result:

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. 
    Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
1: 2014-11-17T19:16:00+00:00
2: 2014-11-17T19:16:00+00:00
3: 2014-11-17T13:16:00-06:00
```

Why would the first one return the same but give the deprecated warning? I'm using an ISO string.

**Code:**

```
var r = {Start:'2014-11-17T20:47:00Z', End:'2014-11-17T19:16:00Z'};

console.log(moment(r.Start).local()); 

            var e = moment(r.Start);
            var f = moment(r.End);

 var res = {exDate:      moment(e).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
            exStartTime: moment(e).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"),
            exEndTime:   moment(f).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A")}

console.log(res );                   
console.log("1: " + moment(res.exEndTime).utc().format());
console.log("2: " + moment.utc(res.exEndTime).format());
console.log("3: " + moment(res.exEndTime).format()); // testing default local format.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors are because of wrapping date already wrapped with moment.
You should use moment like this:

```
var r = {Start:'2014-11-17T20:47:00Z', End:'2014-11-17T19:16:00Z'};
console.log(moment(r.Start).local()); 

var e = moment(r.Start);
var f = moment(r.End);

var res = {
    exDate: e.format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
    exStartTime: e.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"),
    exEndTime: f.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A")
}

console.log(res );                   
console.log("1: " + f.utc().format());
console.log("2: " + f.format());
console.log("3: " + f.format()); // testing default local format.
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors are produced by the last three lines.  For example, when you call `moment(res.exEndTime)` is already a string formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A`.  You are also calling `moment` redundantly.  Essentially, you have:

```
moment(moment(moment('2014-11-17T19:16:00Z')).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A")).format()
```

That's too many moments!

Comment: moment.utc('11/17/2014 01:16 PM') and moment('11/17/2014 01:16 PM') is producing the warning, so this has to do with the date format and not nesting of moment calls.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez - Correct.  I wasn't saying that the nesting was causing the deprecation warning.  I was showing that the OP was indeed calling moment with a deprecated format.  The OP stated they thought they were using ISO strings. Though the source is ISO, it's being mucked into the localized format - hence the deprecation warning.