# Deprecation warning when checking for weekday number

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

In my code I want to check for weekends. This is the code:

```
if(moment(thisDates).day() !== 6 && moment(thisDates).day() !== 0) {}
```

The `thisDates`vaiable contains:

```
String {[[PrimitiveValue]]: "2017-12-12"}
```

The check itself works, but I get a deprication warning from moment:

> moment.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a
>   recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js
>   Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non
>   RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an
>   upcoming major release.

I get that moment dont agree with how i parsed the date i am checking. but how should it be done. Cant figure it out by reading the [docs](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/). Any suggestions?

Comment: For reference, RFC2822 format is `Tue, 12 Dec 2017 09:41:12 UTC`. ISO is `2017-12-12T09:41:12+00:00`. Those are the formats moment wants.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27245626/4248328 And https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987810/4248328 And  https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3488

Comment: `moment("2017-12-12")` is accepted by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) without deprecation warning, can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue?

Comment: `String {[[PrimitiveValue]]: "2017-12-12"` doesn't look like JS to me, what is this from? Is it a templating engine or some server-side script? Are you sure that when it turns this into a JS variable that it keeps it in yyyy-mm-dd format? Or does it re-format it into some locale-specific format which momentJS doesn't like?

Comment: Also `if(moment(thisDates).day() !== 6 && moment(thisDates).day() !== 0) {}` is really inefficient - you're creating two new moment objects, and doing all the parsing and processing associated with that, when one would be sufficient - declare it on the line before and then re-use it, e.g. `var day = moment(thisDates).day(); if( day !== 6 && .day !== 0) {}`

Comment: change my code to your suggestion `var day = moment(thisDates).day(); if( day !== 6 && .day !== 0) {}` Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Jquery.each the wrong way apperanly:

```
dates = ["2017-12-12", "2017-12-13"]
    jQuery.each(dates, function() {
        var thisDates = this;
        if (moment(thisDates).day() !== 6 && moment(thisDates).day() !== 0) {}
      }
```

Change it to:

```
jQuery.each(dates, function(index, value) {
  var thisDates = value;
  if (moment(thisDates).day() !== 6 && moment(thisDates).day() !== 0)
}
```

And now I dont get any warnings

Comment: Some context for future readers: The problem is because (as per http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) "Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value". Therefore in the first (non-working) example above, `this` was an object, with one property for each character in the string, and not a simple string. Using the `value` parameter provided by the callback, as in the second example, is the correct way to access the value being iterated.

Comment: Your question and answer is pretty old. But I would suggest to use `dates.forEach` instead of `jQuery.each`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it’s pretty old. I have moved on to other project”s. But I hope it will help other people working with jQuery.